# How to check if i am passing in anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu like bootstrap 3.0 (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) which follows 
the scroll down and up, but i'd like to have my menu with class "active" corresponding to the div and anchor in the current position of the page.

How can i do this?

this is responsible to follow the scroll

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 90) {
        marginTop = ($(document).scrollTop() - scroll) + marginTop;
        scroll = $(document).scrollTop();

        $("#sideMenu").animate({
            "margin-top": marginTop + "px"
        }, {
            duration: 0,
            queue: false
        });
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using bootstrap or just pointing to an example?

Comment: pointing to an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're asking about the "scroll spy" feature. You need to determine if the user has scrolled to the content.

A quick example using jQuery would be to compare the `$(document).scrollTop` with the `offset().top` of the element you care about.

[Here's one possible library for doing this](https://github.com/thesmart/jquery-scrollspy)